# How to change the base branch for a pull request after creation?

Tags: git, github

I am a bit new to GitHub. I am not sure if what I am trying to do has a name (e.g rebase) but here is what I am trying to do:

1. I forked a repo, lets say foo on `main_branch`.
2. I cloned the repo locally.
3. I did some changes on the `main_branch`.
4. I pushed to my forked repo `main_branch`.
5. I pull requested my `main_branch` to be merged with upstream `main_branch`.

So far so good. However, I want to change the base branch of that pull request now to be `new_feature_branch` instead of `main_branch`. Meaning, if I push any local changed to `new_feature_branch`, it would update the pull request automatically (Just like I do now with `main_branch`).

Is this possible *after* having created the pull request?

Comment: Close the pull request and open a new one. I don't think GitHub has a way to change that part of it. A pull request is essentially a message to someone else: "please add this to your repository" and changing the request while they're using it could be overly confusing. This is of course all up to GitHub—it's not part of Git at all, it's purely GitHub managing who gets asked to do what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the branch your pull request is targeting by simply editing your pull request from the GitHub interface:

[image: Pull request view]

Simply click on *“edit”* to open up the pull request edit form:

[image: Pull request edit form]

And there, you can simply click on the target branch drop down to choose a different branch you want your pull request to apply.

Note that this will *not* change the contents of the commits within your pull request. So after doing this, you might need to rebase the branch in your fork upon that new base to make sure that it will only include the commits you actually made.

To do that, simply run `git rebase upstream/new-base-branch`. Afterwards, you will have to force-push the rewritten commits to your branch using `git push --force`. Note that this will *overwrite* the existing commits on that branch.

---

If however you want to change what branch of *your* repository the pull request should take the commits from (e.g. `my-feature` in the screenshots above), then that will not be possible. You will have to live with that branch for as long as the pull request exists.

Branches are just names though, so if you accidentally used a branch that was meant for something else, you can just temporarily use a different branch name for that other thing until the pull request is resolved.

Comment: But I am trying to change the "from poke:my-feature". Right now it is "from my_name:main_branch", I want it to be "from my_name:new_feature_branch". Is it possible to change it after the pull request is made?

Comment: @AspiringMat Just covered that in an edit to the answer. It’s unfortunately not possible. The source branch name is baked into the pull request and cannot be changed.